# C# and SQL - elegant way to generate script for several tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Im working on database synchronization in my app. It means I have 5 databases, but:

- only in first database product could be added/removed/modified
- this first database saving information about added/removed/modified product to table (with flag 1/2/3 as add/edit/remove and productID)
- so first database generates INSERT script from SELECT, for example:

in my product_changes table (addedRemovedEdited INT, productID INT) I have information:

1, 15 (1 - flag means product with ID = 15 was added), or

2, 15 (2 - flag means product with ID = 15 was edited) etc.

Now using this information I can create script - and there is problem.

At this momment im creating scripts like:

```
SELECT (col1, col2, col3,...) FROM Product_Category;
string query = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES (@a,@b,@c)...";
SELECT (col1,col2,col3,...) FROM Product_price;
query += "INSERT INTO .......";
```

And I need to do it foreach tables which contains information about one single products. So for 10 products I'll have 10 * 12 (12 because there is ~12 tables about one product) blocks of code like INSERT INTO Table 1(....); INSERT INTO TABLE2(....).

Problem is also that, all data need to have same ID in every databases - so I'm using @@identity and put it into insert query. It has to be this way, because product with ID = 10 with name 'Keyboard' in mainDB = product with ID = 10 in DB10.

And the question - maybe some of you know any better (becouse that one is not so good) solution how can I create those scripts? Like query, which will take all information from my string[] a = {"Product", "Product_price", "Product_category"} tables and generate INSERT queries but - most important - where I can add @@identity.

@EDIT: I forgot. I found that solution: [how i can generate programmatically "insert into" data script file from a database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226571/how-i-can-generate-programmatically-insert-into-data-script-file-from-a-databa)

Well, it does generate scripts, but with auto-incremented ID. And I need to add information in right order (as middle tables) for example:

```
INSERT INTO Product(.....) VALUES (...);
SET @pID = @@identity FROM Product;

INSERT INTO Price (priceID,.....) VALUES (...);
SET @prID = @@identity FROM Price;

INSERT INTO Product_price (priceID, productID,...) VALUES (@prID, @pID)
```

Comment: You should add the type of server you are using to your tags.

Comment: Why can't you just replace the tables in the other databases with views? Are the databases on different servers?

Comment: Yes. Databases could be actually in another place in the world :P (of course if You mean server as machine, not structure. Structure is same everywhere)