# SQL Import / Export Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, export

I've got a Windows Form App linked to a Microsoft SQL Server database with loads of tables.

I've got 2 buttons over there (Import and Export) and when clicking on EXPORT, this should trigger a Stored Procedure that will generate a string to export the data only (loads of INSERT statements - not the table definition). The string generated by this will be saved as a script file. This will be later used to IMPORT that data on to a different database.

I was thinking of creating a stored procedure to do this (but I'm not entirely sure how) or if there is a better approach for this, I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are tools, provided by your db vendor. Almost all got pretty simple tools for exporting data like `insert script...`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that... It's Microsoft SQL Server... I'm going to edit the question now.

Comment: Yes, there are tools that can do this, for example from the TASK options there is a GENERATE SCRIPTS function, I want something exactly like that, but that needs to be done as I said through a function or a stored procedure.

Comment: @mrc -- for future reference, you should tag your questions appropriately to attract people who are knowledgeable on the particular subjects, e.g. SQL Server.

Comment: If this is a one-off, just write a script.   Making it a stored proc won't have any benefits.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226571/how-i-can-generate-programmatically-insert-into-data-script-file-from-a-databa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Management Studio to generate the script.

Right-click on the database in Object explorer, from context menu choose "tasks", then "generate scripts".

In the dialog, select the tables you want the data scripted out from. On the next page set the destination, and click on the "advanced" button. There find the "type of data to script" option - choose "data only".

[edit] As per the edited question, you can automate this using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter, the same lib the SSMS uses.

Comment: I know this is an option, but I'm not interested in something like this as this is fairly time consuming and this application should be used by our sales department to Export/Import data easily. So when taking this in consideration, they don't have SSMS or even if they do, they might not have the skills to do this. But pushing a button to generate the export script and later to import it to a different database is a lot easier :)

Comment: That's a really good idea, can that also be used to only script the data from certain tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a script that will generate an insert statement for you, you could build it with a query, like this...

```
SELECT 
    'SELECT ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',''' + 
        VarcharField1 + ''',''' + 
        VarcharField2 + ''' UNION ALL'
FROM Example
```

If you display the results as text (Ctrl+T), you can easily grab it for further manipulation. It will generate something like this...

```
SELECT 1,'Row1Field1','Row1Field2' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Row2Field1','Row2Field2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Row3Field1','Row3Field2' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Row4Field1','Row4Field2' UNION ALL
```

You would need to put an `INSERT [TableName]` before the results and trim the last `UNION ALL`, but this works. I've used it several times before. [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a6e1/3)